# Certain songs will not burn to CD in iTunes

Tags: itunes

First time I have tried to burn a CD since I was upgraded to 12.2.  All will burn to CD except for three songs, two of which I just purchased.  They show up on the playlist, but are darkened, not highlighted to copy to CD.  I tried going back to the earlier iTunes version, but then it would not open my library at all, saying it had been created on a later version.  Any help to be  had?  It would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: If you look in your Music > iTunes_old folder, every time iTunes is updated, the prior version of your catalog is backed up. If you want to run the older iTunes, then find the version of your catalog that corresponds to that version.